# SAP b1 Service Layer - New Contact person for a Business Partner (REST API)

Tags: service-layer, sapb1

Would anybody know how to create a new Contact Persons for a Business Partner via the Service Layer (REST API json) ?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a "ContactEmployees" collections on the "BusinessPartner" entity. Send a PATCH request to the BP, something like:

```
PATCH https://server:50000/b1s/v1/BusinessPartners('C00001')

{
    "ContactEmployees": 
       {
        "Name": "Arthur Dent"
       }
}
```

(I deleted my first answer because I confused BP contacts with the entity for 'activities' which is also referred to as 'contacts' in the API.)